# Is it possible to format a cell in Excel with optional decimal point when not required?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

If I use this cell format: `###,##0.##`, and the number is an integer, for example, `12`, cell appears like this: `12,` which looks ugly.

Is there a way integer numbers to be displayed as integers and decimal numbers to be displayed with 2 decimal places?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Format for non-integers eg #,##0.00, then use conditional formatting to identify integers eg A1=INT(A1), then in the Number format options choose a suitable format.

To get your numbers to line up when aligned to the right, you might want to force spacing to match the non-integers by using underscore characters like this: #,##0_._0_0

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the custom format to:

```
###,##0.00
```

Then `12` will display as `12.00`

Comment: "Is there a way integer numbers to be displayed as integers and... "

Comment: Try this formula to get the result: **=IF(MOD(A1,1),ROUND(A1,2),A1)**